# Gerrit + GitLab's CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit, gitlab-ci

We have been using Gerrit for code review, but now we want to use GitLab's CI as one of the code review reviewers. Basically if the GitLab CI build is successful the review would pass for the user represented by GitLab's CI.

I guess I could set up a couple of hooks to get both systems to talk, but I am wondering if someone already did this and/or if someone could give me pointers on how to get it running.

Comment: I guess it's rather unusual to use GitLab CI without using GitLab, hence it's unlikely to find a GitLab CI integration for any other code review platform than GitLab.

Comment: Hi OP, have you given a chance to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at "yiree" (Jiri)?  It is perhaps a bit more than you want, and it has its own CL flow, but the hooks between a git-like repo and Gerrit are there: https://github.com/vanadium/go.jiri

Comment: How does Jiri help to integrate with GitLab *CI* (Continuous Integration)?

Comment: It has the hooks for Git and Gerrit.  Specifically it has Gerrit GetChange, which, if the build is successful, can push or mirror to GitLab, which would then build the code as part of the GitLab CI.

Comment: My understand is that the OP is using GitLab CI *without* using GitLab, i.e. there is no repository to mirror to, and Gerrit should talk directly to GitLab CI.

Comment: I don't care if I need to create a project on gitlab to use Gitlab CI, but I fail to see how Jiri would help. Gitlab and Gerrit have different philosophies (branches vs patches) how would I mirror both things?

Comment: You would get the changes (patches) from Gerrit, and `git apply` them to the master branch of the GitLab repo.